# Convergence of a vector sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If I have to prove that an infinite sequence of vectors $  \{A_n \} $ diverges, can I do so by merely proving that one of the components of the vector diverges - that is the scalar series formed by one of the components of the vector. If there is such a theorem could you please point me to it?

I have an engineering background and this question came up in an optimization class so my apologies if it is a very stupid question.

Comment: yes you can....

Comment: In most cases, @Surb is right (that you are correct).  However we need to be careful about the *topology* of the vector space you are working with.  For engineering applications this will ordinarily mean a finite-dimensional Euclidean space $\mathbb R^n$, in which case your intuition is correct:  a sequence of vectors converges if and only if each of the finitely many "components" converge (so if any component diverges, the sequence as a whole diverges).  But not every topological vector space has this property, so it would improve the Question to identify your vector space.